# How do I change the credit card linked to our civiCRM account?

Tags: user-account, hosting-providers

I used my personal credit/debit card to set-up civiCRM for my organization and now we have an organizational bank account.  I'd like to stop paying personally for the hosting service.  How do I make that change?

Answer (score 1):

you can update your subscription [using this form](https://civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=125), and cancel the billing on the current card (otherwise it will continue to be billed on a monthly basis). The monthly email receipts have the link to interrupt the automatic billing.

If you have any questions, assuming this is related to CiviCRM Spark (i.e. your CiviCRM URL looks like "your-org.civicrm.org"), please contact spark@civicrm.org.